# In GWT, why image.setURL("/SimpleCaptcha.jpg") to refresh the image doesn't work in firefox?

Tags: image, gwt

I'm building a system to let user type in captcha, & user can refresh the image to get another captcha words. so I used this code to refresh image.

```
    captchaImage.setUrl("/SimpleCaptcha.jpg");
```

it works fine in Chome, but not working in Firefox.

So is there any other simple way to refresh image that work in all Browsers in GWT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does nothing if your new URL is the same one as it was before. If you generate a new image with the same filename, an easy workaround is to make the URL unique so it forces the browser to reload:

```
captchaImage.setUrl("/SimpleCaptcha.jpg?" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This makes the URL say something like `"/SimpleCaptcha.jpg?89109801890180130189"`

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the captcha image which is generated server side in a folder under the web app:

> webapp/generatedcaptcha/SimpleCaptcha.jpg

The, in the GWT java code, do something like this:

```
Image image = new Image("http://yourdomain/yourapp/generatedcaptcha/SimpleCaptcha.jpg");
```

It should work.

Comment: And this captcha image maintanance needs huge coding ..like saving in it folder ..then delete all those captchas from folder ..etc

Answer (score 0):

`/path` is taking absolute path of from the domain which indicates the browser the file is at `http://domain/SimpleCaptcha.jpg`

If you wanna use relative path, you need to remove the slash:

```
captchaImage.setUrl("SimpleCaptcha.jpg");
```

Chrome works because it tests both relative and absolute path. Firefox does not work because it is more strict.